# R Можно ли поместить .csv файл в собственный пакет?

Tags: r

Мы хотим чтобы при установке нашего пакета, пользователь так же получал нужный .csv файл. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предпочтительным способом является включение данных в бинарном виде. Это можно сделать, разместив в директории `data` файлы с расширением `.RData`, которые создаются с помощью функции `saveRDS`. Можно также хранить образ (множество переменных) в `R/sysdata.rda`, которые создаётся с помощью функции `save`.

CSV можно хранить в любой удобной поддиректории внутри `inst`. Например, в `inst/raw-data`. Тогда внутри пакета доступ получаем следующим образом:

```r
system.file("raw-data/my.csv", package = packageName())
```